# ping and identify Cisco model without physical access or login?

Tags: cisco, ping, nmap

There are several Cisco devices on my network which I can find with `ping` or `nmap` but I have no idea what the type (e.g. switches, routers) or specific model is. Is there some way to find this out without physical access or having a login to any of these?

Comment: If [CDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Discovery_Protocol) is enabled, you might get more information by running a CDP client.

Comment: that is a good answer, although Cisco's exam guide suggests `no cdp enable`

Comment: @T.Webster CDP is usually only disabled facing untrusted ports, like your ISP or a customer port. In a more enterprise context, CDP is used by Cisco APs and Cisco phones, so it's usually enabled on access ports regardless of what the exam guide might suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find some information by using [nmap's -O](http://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html) switch. You can also get the information using SNMP but you would have to look at [Cisco's MIB's](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/servlet/index) to figure out which one to use.

Comment: e.g. nmap  -A 10.0.0.1 works also

Answer (score 1):

ICMP cannot be used to extract information like that.

Without a login you maybe have one option:

Hope that SNMP is enabled and using a known community string like "public". SNMP will at least reveal an OID you can tie back to a model number using SNMPwalk. Plenty of tutorials out there on how to do this.